# Why can't a client speak directly (!) with a WCF server , instead of using a proxy class that does that?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client-server

I'm currently learning the basics of WCF , and I stumbled upon the following flow :

[image]

Meaning that my client needs to speak with a Proxy class , that communicates with the WCF server .

Why can't I (the client) speak directly with the server , instead of using a third party for the job ?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from calling the [IRequestChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.irequestchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) methods directly, it is just a PITA to do it when making a proxy makes it so much easier.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing stopping you from **not** using a c# WCF proxy client to communicate with a WCF service, you could always do without and use say raw TCP/HTTP/pipes/MSMQ.   However, doing so generally requires alot of effort and time - time during which most people would generally prefer to spend reading the *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

### Heavy?

WCF proxies are actually not as heavy as it may sound. They're not really "3rd party" either.  There're generally nothing more than light-weight classes *compiled in* with your application.  They don't run say *out-of-process* as may happen in certain COM scenarios.

The notion of a "3rd party" proxy is not unique to WCF.  DCOM also has the concept of proxies, but unlike WCF, they are created for you behind the scenes and are unable to be avoided. Sometimes, as mentioned, they even run in another process! WCF, or should I say *SOAP services* (generally), differs from DCOM because the client proxies are not required.  They just make the use case of using a SOAP service *easier*.  Luckily that part of Windows had to make way for a hyperspace bypass, so the use of DCOM in contemporary applications is essentially no more.

The client proxies help your life by:

- **encapsulating** and serializing the method call into a request message (usually SOAP)
- **abstracting** you from the underlying transport when the call to the service is made transmitting the request message from the prior step. i.e. using TCP; HTTP; MSMQ etc APIs.  Want your TCP WCF service to accept a local named pipe client?  Easy just change the config file, no code change is generally required!
- **deserializing** the response message into a user friendly c# object(s)
- handles all the tedious; complex and necessary **security** for you in the form of security tokens; cookies et al

### When is WCF not WCF?

So going back to your question again:

> Why can't a client speak directly (!) with a WCF server , instead of using a proxy class that does that?

...when you consider that WCF unifies all the comms APIs into a single API; abstracts and encapsulates a SOAP service, then we could say that all WCF clients by definition use WCF proxies to talk to a WCF service.

As soon as a client explicitly uses **raw** TCP; MSMQ; HTTP; named pipes APIs in code, it essentially **stops being a WCF client** (remember WCF is all about unified comms) and instead becomes a **SOAP client** (or perhaps REST).  I would even argue that using the [IRequestChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.irequestchannel) interface with its [Request()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195350(v=vs.110).aspx) method, introduces a *messaging* concept that was not apparent with standard WCF client proxy code (even if it still abstracts transports from the user).  By way of comparison, if I add a MSMQ binding to my pure WCF-client-proxy-using-app's WCF config, my code generally doesn't take on an *asynchronous messaging model* typically associated with MSMQ.  That's the nice thing about WCF.

Of course the server, written in WCF, will be quite content in the knowledge that it considers itself "WCF" regardless of whether clients think it is WCF; SOAP or *some scary XML payload being shot over TCP* in much the same way as the deity that is *Pluto*, considers itself to be a planet regardless of what classification system happens to be in fashion at the time.

- If you want to treat the service as a WCF service - use WCF client proxies (because we generally don't care about the underlying SOAP message being sent about)
- If you want to talk to the service directly without proxies, then you should think about the remote service as a SOAP service and so arm yourself with not only low-level comms APIs but also how to construct and process SOAP messages

### Are non-Proxy Approaches Recommended?

Whilst you could do without the proxy, it is **not** recommended because if you wanted to change *security, transports, max message lengths, protocols such as JSON, add `async` methods*, **you would be required to perform a great deal of code changes to your non-proxy-using-app** compared to the proxy approach.

Like the starship *Heart of Gold*, WCF is *"Glad to be of service"* but understands should you desire *manual helm control*.

---

Gratuitous references to Douglas Adam's fine radio play; TV mini-series and book *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.  Why not press the **Don't Panic** button and read it today?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm pretty new to WCF myself, but I'm pretty sure the proxy class is there to give you the types you need your code to reference.  When you make a WCF call, you are serializing data, so you need a class to define that. The proxy allows you to write code against it, acting like you know what its methods and data contracts are, but when the code is actually executed, a WCF call is made and serialized messages are sent back and forth.